# O que é &quot em Java?

Tags: java, sintaxe

Gostaria de saber o que significa **&quot** em java.

Exemplo: usado para formar o nome de um objeto:

```
ClasseObjeto celula+&quot;&quot;+col+&quot;_&quot;+lin = new ClasseObjeto();
```

Comment: Texto mal formado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você deve ter tirado isso [desse link aqui](http://www.guj.com.br/t/usando-laco-for-para-instanciar-objetos/81750/4).

`&quot;` é a sequência de escape em HTML que representa as aspas duplas (`"`).

Ou seja, esse texto deveria ser isso:

```
ClasseObjeto celula+""+col+"_"+lin = new ClasseObjeto();
```

No entanto, por causa de algum problema do site ou do usuário que postou isso lá, as aspas acabaram sendo convertidas para `&quot;`. Observe que nesse código, o `<` também foi zoado dessa mesma forma e se tornou `&lt;`.

E por sinal, mesmo arrumando-se esse problema, isso não compila e nem chega perto de compilar. Em Java não é possível concatenar-se nomes de variáveis para criar-se outras variáveis.

Comment: Muito bem esclarecido. Obrigado!